# How to patch a ConfigMap in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, patch, configmap, coredns

Kubernetes ships with a `ConfigMap` called `coredns` that lets you specify DNS settings. I want to modify or patch a small piece of this configuration by adding:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  upstreamNameservers: |
    ["1.1.1.1", "1.0.0.1"]
```

I know I can use `kubectrl edit` to edit the `coredns` `ConfigMap` is there some way I can take the above file containing only the settings I want to insert or update and have it merged on top of or patched over the existing `ConfigMap`?

The reason for this is that I want my deployment to be repeatable using CI/CD. So, even if I ran my Helm chart on a brand new Kubernetes cluster, the settings above would be applied.

Answer (score 53):

This will apply the same patch to that single field:

```
kubectl patch configmap/coredns \
  -n kube-system \
  --type merge \
  -p '{"data":{"upstreamNameservers":"[\"1.1.1.1\", \"1.0.0.1\"]"}}'
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add this into a Helm chart somehow?

Comment: Hi @MuhammadRehanSaeed, Helm is for deploying and managing 'artifacts' or self contained systems. I don't think it's appropriate to use Helm to modify system configs.

Comment: This answer is correct; but, there are more ways to patch a resource. See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/

Comment: This is invaluable for sooo many use cases. It's a pity this cannot be found on the docs. Thank you!

Comment: @ Jordan Liggitt this way doesn't work if the whole config under data field is in form of embedded json string.

Comment: I am not sure if this will also work for file-like keys. This works perfectly for property-like keys.

Comment: @esahmo for that case I prefer to use `jq`. E.g. 
```kubectl get configmap/coredns -n kube-system -o json | jq '.data.Corefile += "localnet:53 {\n    errors\n    cache 30\n    forward . '"$(minikube ip)"'\n}\n"' | kubectl apply -f -```

Answer (score 4):

you should try something like this:

```
kubectl get cm some-config -o yaml | run 'sed' commands to make updates | kubectl create cm some-config -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: The question asks how to do this in a CI/CD environment where manually editing some files is not possible.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed This answer does not involve manually editing files.

Comment: This is a more general answer which is correct and you should be able to run this script in your CI/CD pipeline

Answer (score 1):

you can edit it using vi as follows:

```
    kubectl edit cm -n kube-system coredns
```

or you can export it to apply any changes using `kubectl get cm -n kube-system -o yaml --export` then use `kubectl apply -f fileName.yaml` to apply your changes

Comment: The question asks how to do this in a CI/CD environment where manually editing some files is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As ConfigMaps are used to mount configuration files to Pod, it seems like [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#container-configuration) is what you are looking for. ConfigMaps inside of containers will update automatically if the underlying ConfigMap or Secret is modified.

You can specify configMap location:

`configMapVolume(mountPath: '/etc/mount3', configMapName: 'my-config'),`

**Update:**

Ok, I guess this does not solve your issue.
Other thing that comes to my mind is `kubectl create configmap` with a pipe to `kubectl replace`
So the whole command would look like this:

`kubectl create configmap NAME --from-file file.name -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl replace -f -`

Note that this replaces whole file, so just `replace` should work too.