# patch a configmap from file or with json

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, configmap

I want to edit a configmap from `aws-auth` during a vagrant deployment to give my vagrant user access to the EKS cluster. I need to add a snippet into the existing `aws-auth` configmap. How do i do this programmatically?

If you do a `kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth` you get

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::123:role/nodegroup-abc123
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-05-30T03:00:18Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "19055217"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/aws-auth
  uid: 0000-0000-0000
```

i need to enter this bit in there somehow.

```
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::123:user/sergeant-poopie-pants
      username: sergeant-poopie-pants
      groups:
      - system:masters
```

I've tried to do a `cat <<EOF > {file} EOF` then patch from file. But that option doesn't exist in `patch` only in the `create` context.

I also found this: [How to patch a ConfigMap in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54571185/267490)

but it didn't seem to work. or perhaps i didn't really understand the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to automate things. The direct way would be `kubectl get configmap -o yaml ... > cm.yml && patch ... < cm.yml > cm2.yml && kubectl apply -f cm2.yml` or something like that. You might want to use a script that parses and modifies the YAML data rather than a literal patch to make it less brittle. You could also do something like `EDITOR="myeditscript" kubectl edit configmap ...` but that's more clever that I would want to do.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that the `mapRoles` and `mapUsers` are actually treated as a string, even though it is structured data (yaml).

While this problem is solvable by jsonpatch, it is much easier using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and `kubectl apply` like this:

```
kubectl get cm aws-auth -o json \
  | jq --arg add "`cat add.yaml`" '.data.mapUsers = $add' \
  | kubectl apply -f -
```

Where `add.yaml` is something like this (notice the lack of extra indentation):

```
- userarn: arn:aws:iam::123:user/sergeant-poopie-pants
  username: sergeant-poopie-pants
  groups:
  - system:masters
```

See also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html for more information.

Comment: Note that "add" is a little misleading here as you're actually _replacing_ the value (as written).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `kubectl patch` one-liner for patching the `aws-auth` configmap:

```
kubectl patch configmap -n kube-system aws-auth -p '{"data":{"mapUsers":"[{\"userarn\": \"arn:aws:iam::0000000000000:user/john\", \"username\": \"john\", \"groups\": [\"system:masters\"]}]"}}'
```

Comment: this will remove existing entries and add new