# How to patch and update a ConfigMap in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a ConfigMap as following:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: health-ip
data:
  ip.json: |-
    [
      1.1.1.1,
      2.2.2.2
    ]
```

I want to modify/append or patch a small piece of this configuration by adding ip `3.3.3.3` to the ConfigMap so that it becomes:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: health-ip
data:
  ip.json: |-
    [
      1.1.1.1,
      2.2.2.2,
      3.3.3.3
    ]
```

How can it do this using `kubectl patch` or equivalent?

Comment: `ConfigMap` is a dictionary from string to string. It has no understanding of data structure. If you want to do that - you need to do it entirely manually using string functions or whatever other programming languages facilities you have.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571185/how-to-patch-a-configmap-in-kubernetes

Comment: The answer on that link deletes the existing ip's to replace with whatever is mentioned in patch.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to add without replace. As mentioned in comment by **zerkms**, `configmaps` does not undestand structure data.

You have a couple of options to achive what you want:

1. Keep a "template" file of your configmap, update and apply when you need;
2. Automate the first task with a script that reads the configmap value and append the new value.
3. Use the `kubectl path` passing the whole ip list.