# kubectl changes the value in configmap

Tags: kubectl

I wanted to update the deployed configmap through the kubectl patch command, but I was not familiar with the patch syntax. After trying, I found that it did not take effect

This is my configmap

```
apiVersion: cloudcore.config.kubeedge.io/v1alpha2
kind: CloudCore
kubeAPIConfig:
  kubeConfig: ""
  master: ""
modules:
  cloudHub:
    advertiseAddress:
    - 10.102.26.35
    dnsNames:
    - 
    nodeLimit: 1000
    tlsCAFile: /etc/kubeedge/ca/rootCA.crt
    tlsCertFile: /etc/kubeedge/certs/edge.crt
    tlsPrivateKeyFile: /etc/kubeedge/certs/edge.key
    unixsocket:
      address: unix:///var/lib/kubeedge/kubeedge.sock
      enable: true
    websocket:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      enable: true
      port: 10000
    quic:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      enable: false
      maxIncomingStreams: 10000
      port: 10001
    https:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      enable: true
      port: 10002
  cloudStream:
    enable: true
    streamPort: 10003
    tunnelPort: 10004
  dynamicController:
    enable: false
  router:
    enable: false
  iptablesManager:
    enable: true
    mode: external
```

I want to replace the 10.102.26.35 ip with 192.168.1.20

I tried to use the following command, but it didn't work, someone can help me

```
kubectl patch configmap cloudcore -n kubeedge --type merge -p '{"data":{"advertiseAddress":"[\"10.102.26.35\", \"192.168.1.20\"]"}}'
```

Comment: Can you try editing the deployment using  `kubectl edit deployment` and replace  the IP 10.102.26.35 with 192.168.1.20, then apply the changes using `kubectl apply`

Comment: Do not want to use edit, or modify yaml files, want to go through patch

Answer (score 1):

As per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63578377/19230181) There is no way to add without replace. Configmaps does not understand structure data. This you need to do by manually.

Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571185/how-to-patch-a-configmap-in-kubernetes) and [Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) for more information